# Does the word "ragbag" have strong negative connotations?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm not a native speaker. I've checked with urbandictionary site which showed a few quite negative interpretations. But I also saw several (relatively)neutral usages which seemed to me absolutely appropriate for even formal contexts. What do you think?

I mean, from what I see, it always has at least some minor negative connotation, sure. Question is how strong those connotations usually are? When applied to an object or a thing, is this just a synonym to "mishmash" or is it something worse? (again, not a native speaker)

Some decent examples that I've seen on the wordhippo:

> This wasn't a **ragbag** of promises and emollient phrases designed to patch up a political problem, as some previous ones have been.

or

> This is a **ragbag** of delights and compromises, as all such compilations are.

But I rather not paste here examples from urbandictionary :)

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you'd share the examples that you thought were relatively neutral. Thank you!

Comment: If it's applied to a person it's negative.  Applied to an object it depends a lot on the details.

Comment: It's neutral if describing something everyone understood as piecemeal, but otherwise it's somewhat to strongly negative. If you say that someone's college paper is a "ragbag of ideas" it means the piece is not very coherent. If a "ragbag of half-baked ideas" it's quite a disparagement. Context, of course, is everything.